# Creating a profile sub page and filling with Webform data

Tags: 7, users

I'm looking to add an extra sub page to a user's profile that will contain the user's answers to a webform that they have previously submitted. I'm having trouble figuring out how to add this subpage.

Any direction appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand well your question, what you want is a view that show the answer to a webform.

So you can create a view filtred by user, display it in a block and invoke it in the template of your profil page.